# Server side events not firing the first time when asp validator used into the page

Tags: asp.net

I am created a page with update panel and used Asp.net validation controls to be 
   validated the page is making an issue is "i am straightly going to submit the page
   and page gets validated properly then, i am going to click/select any controls on 
   the page is not get post back"

The below code i am used

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<div id="divMyDataManualEntry" runat="server">
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
<td style="width: 5%;" valign="top">
<asp:Label ID="lblGeo" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Text="Geography"></asp:Label><span
class="redtext">*</span>
</td>
<td valign="top" style="width: 15%">
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlgeo" TabIndex="1" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Width="100%"
OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlgeo_SelectedIndexChanged"  AutoPostBack="true"> 
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlgeo"
ValidationGroup="Submit" InitialValue="-1" ErrorMessage="Select Geography"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</td>                     
</tr> </table>
<table width="100%" id="BtnContainer" runat="server">
<tr>
<td align="center">
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:return IsValidated();"
ValidationGroup="Submit" CssClass="Keybutton" TabIndex="14" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnreset" runat="server" Text="Reset" CssClass="Keybutton" TabIndex="15"
OnClick="btnReset_click" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Add CausesValidation=false for all the controls which generate postback apart from the submit button

Comment: I tried it already i never get any solution for the problem

Comment: It would be easier if you show your code, what have you tried and what is not working

Comment: I am used server side controls fire server side events only but validation could be made by validation controls so if i submit the form by using a button is only linked with validation group not other and other controls are having 'CauseValidation=false'.